# Computing Partial Differentiation of Composite Function $u(e^\tau\cosh{y}, e^\tau\sinh{y})$ Using the Chain Rule

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $u = u(t,x): \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} \ $be a solution to the wave equation$(-\partial_{tt}u + \partial_{xx}u = 0)$, and let $v = v(\tau, y): (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$
$$
v(\tau, y) := u(e^\tau\cosh{y}, e^\tau\sinh{y})
$$
be determined.

Show that the following equation is satisfied:
$$
-\partial_{\tau\tau}v + \partial_{yy}v = 0.
$$

**What I did:**
Let $k(\tau, y) := e^\tau \cosh{y}$, and let $l(\tau, y) := e^\tau \sinh{y}$. i.e. $v(\tau, y) = u(k(\tau, y), l(\tau, y))$. Then,
$$
∂_\tau v = \frac{\partial}{\partial k}u(k(\tau, y), l(\tau, y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial\tau} k(\tau, y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial l}u(k(\tau, y), l(\tau, y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial\tau} l(\tau, y)\\
∂_{\tau\tau} v =\ ??
$$

Comment: Did you do something?

Comment: First, $∂_\tau v$ was obtained. However, I cannot solve for $∂_{\tau\tau} v$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct, only, imo, is more good to use different letters for different purposes, or use numbers. For example, if we take $u=u(t,x)$, then partial derivatives are better to write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = u_{1}^{'}$. When $t$ and $x$ is also functions $u=u(t,x)=u(t(\tau,y), x(\tau,y))$, then we use chain rule
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}$$
Second derivative is calculated in same way
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}=\\
=\left[\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial t}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}\right]\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}
+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2 t}{\partial \tau^2}+\\
+\left[\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t\partial x}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}\right]\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}
+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \tau^2}$$
Hope, you can continue from here.